# Does The Starcraft 2 MMR transfer to a different server?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-terran

I play zerg in ranked master league on the Europe server, got my 1000 wins and I want to play terran now (I am horrible with terran). Do you know if my MMR will be the same on the Americas server or anyother, so that I can start from scratch in bronze hopefully?

I am really struggling to play against master players as terran, I can maybe take a silver player. That is how bad my terran game is. I would love to practice with bronze-silver players first, before I rank against stronger players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have a different account on different servers.  So when you log in there, you'll be asked to create a username for the first time, and you will have no games played.  You'll play the 5 placement matches to determine your league when you start.

So there is no MMR transfer between regions, otherwise (logically) you wouldn't need to play 5 placement matches.

Aside from switching servers (which is annoying because of lag), you can use your unranked ladder option to off-race with.

Comment: Do multiple user accounts on the same server (but using the same purchased copy of the game) share a MMR?

Comment: How can you get two different accounts with one copy of the game on a single server?